# Passing URL as an environment variable in docker run

Tags: rest, docker, environment-variables

My docker container needs to connect to other system via http. so , I have export an REST_BASE_URL in environment variable and pass it on docker run using -e parameter . Unfortunately, I am ending up with below error . Can anybody help me out ?

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-eREST_BASE_URL=https://some.server.url\": stat -eREST_BASE_URL=https://some.server.url: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Comment: Can you send some code of your Dockerfile? it must be something wrong with building image(Entrypoint in Dockerfile)

Comment: Share the complete docker run.

Comment: @YashJagdale I am not using entrypoint rather I am using CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using docker-compose.

Below is the sample :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
   receiving:
     build: .
     restart: always
     environment:
       - "REST_BASE_URL=http://some.server.url"
     ports:
       - 8080:8080
```

Comment: you can do it with docker by using `docker run -e REST_BASE_URL=http://some.server.url -p REST_BASE_URL=http://some.server.url`

Comment: Thats what I did earlier ... due to character escape stuff, It is throwing exception and trace is pasted as a part of problem statement